Fatha + dagger alif (ArabTeX)
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
 
\begin{document}
\setarab
\fullvocalize
\arabtrue
\begin{RLtext}
a.s-.sir_a.ta
\end{RLtext}
\end{document}

produces

while
\begin{RLtext}
a.s-.sira.ta
\end{RLtext}

produces

Is it possible with ArabTeX to combine the two and obtain a dagger Alif following a consonant with fatha as in

No combination of | and " produces the desired effect, while ra_a produces some sort of error.

arabtex starts with a line \def \thedatum {22.08.2003}. That means it hasn't been updated since 20 years.  It is an impressive package that demonstrates how far you can get with pdftex, but it is not really recommended nowadays. If you want to typeset arabic, use lualatex and babel, see e.g. https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/locale-arabic.html

@UlrikeFischer thank you for your comment. I understand that ArabTeX is pretty much outdated, however I find it extremely convenient for the purpose of transliteration, especially in that (if you are consistent with your writing of Arabic text) you can automatically change the transliteration style by modifying one line of code. The transliteration system for luatex appears more primitive in this respect. Any suggestions on transliteration for modern engines would be greatly appreciated.

Ok, I see that ArabXeTeX might be a good solution to my problem, thank you!

Imho arabluatex offers transliteration, and I would prefer luatex to xetex long term. See the newest latex news.

Looking at the code it seems that there might be a way to add this to the transliteration scheme, but the basic scheme does not allow this, as _ serves more or less as a switch that changes the following fatha to a dagger. It is also not easily possible to just insert another fatha (that is, two fathas in a row). And I am also unsure whether it is possible to add the dagger that way, because it might eventually sit at a quirky position.

@AlephBeth With babel you can modify the transliteration by means of transforms (eg, to ‘unvowelize’ the text). You can also add new rules, and I managed to create a new one to insert a dagger alif inline (isolated), but it’s placed high, and I’m not sure how to get it on the baseline (I can’t find it in Unicode – perhaps a font feature?).

@JasperHabicht, @JavierBezos Thank you both for your comments! I myself would not venture into modifying the transliteration scheme, but it was made possible in arabXeTeX by .sira_a.ta (which seems a logical choice). Indeed the positioning of dagger alif is a font feature: for example it works nicely in Scheherazade (placed centrally over the carrier), but not equally well in Amari (placed on the top line, below the corresponding fatha).
